# Fade away on scroll

Tags: html, css

I want to have many blocks of text on the page, but would like it so that when the user scrolls the current block fades away and the new one slides up. That way it is just a repeat process for every block of text I have. I want to achieve similar effect as on [this website](http://alessandroscarpellini.it/). I'm looking for a solution using pure CSS.

Comment: You have your question marked `javascript`, but mention in the body pure CSS; which is it?

Comment: This is probably not practicable using only css.

Answer (score -1):

very crude example in pure css, obviously you'd want more divs etc.

```css
div{width:100%;}
.a{background-color:white;opacity:0.7;}
.b{background-color:white;opacity:0.4;}
.c{background-color:white;opacity:0;}
#top{position:fixed;top:0%;min-height:15%;}
#topdown{position:fixed;top:15%;min-height:15%;}
#middle{position:fixed;top:30%;min-height:40%;}
#downtop{position:fixed;top:70%;min-height:15%;}
#bottom{position:fixed;top:85%;min-height:15%;}
```

```html
<div id="top" class="a">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="topdown" class="b">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="middle" class="c">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="downtop" class="b">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="bottom" class="a">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="main">extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text vextremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text vextremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text vextremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text vextremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text vextremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text extremely long text </div>
```